# Split file or extract lines that differ based on a pattern

Tags: unix, sed

I have a tab separated file like this:

```
Supercontig_1.1 400  1500  1       4
Supercontig_1.1 400  1500  2       4
Supercontig_1.1 20000  138566  1       1
Supercontig_1.1 20000  138566  2       1
Supercontig_1.2 300  1000  1       2
Supercontig_1.2 300  1000  2       2
Supercontig_1.2 1300  15000  1       2
Supercontig_1.2 1300  15000  2       2
Supercontig_1.3 0  10000  1       5
Supercontig_1.3 0  10000  2       5
```

And I want to extract all lines based on the pattern "Supercontig_1.X" into a separate file. I.e. all lines with Supercontig_1.1 in one file, all lines with Supercontig_1.2 in another...
I tried looking into the "sed" command, but I am not sure how to use it when the search pattern is not the same for all lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $0 >$1 }' infile
```

That yields:

```
==> Supercontig_1.1 <==
Supercontig_1.1 400  1500  1       4
Supercontig_1.1 400  1500  2       4
Supercontig_1.1 20000  138566  1       1
Supercontig_1.1 20000  138566  2       1

==> Supercontig_1.2 <==
Supercontig_1.2 300  1000  1       2
Supercontig_1.2 300  1000  2       2
Supercontig_1.2 1300  15000  1       2
Supercontig_1.2 1300  15000  2       2

==> Supercontig_1.3 <==
Supercontig_1.3 0  10000  1       5
Supercontig_1.3 0  10000  2       5
```

I don't see your fields separated with comma, only spaces. Change the field separator (`FS`) if is that case, like: `BEGIN { FS=","; }` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: You're right. I have a tab separated file. Fixed the mistake. Can I write "\t" as a separator? How to make output into separate files?

Comment: @Jon: `AWk` by default split fields with any whitespace character, including tabs. You only must change the value of `FS` when separator is a different character, like commas.

Comment: BTW, how can I get the output files to be tab separated? I tried to use several versions of FS="\t", but then I get every line printed to the stdout.

Comment: @Jon: How are fields separated in your input file? Only spaces, tabs, mixed?

Comment: @Jon: Then fields will be tab separated in the output too, because the script prints the line without modifying it (`$0`). Did you test it?

Comment: How stupid! I tested on the wrong file all the time! It works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^((\S*)\s.*)\n\2.*/\1/;ta;s/(\S*).*/\/^\1\/w\1/;P;D' file | 
sed -nf - file
```

This will only work if the file is sorted.

If the file is not sorted use:

```
sort -u -k1,1 file | sed -r 's#^(\S*).*#/^\1/w\1#' | sed -nf - file
```